# Backbone.js - How I can get values from collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I am using jquery, backbonejs and underscorejs for my project.
My question is, how I can get values from the collection given?

BranchModel

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

  var BranchModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

  return BranchModel;

});
```

BranchCollection

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/branch/BranchModel'
], function($, _, Backbone, BranchModel){
  var BranchCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: BranchModel,
    url: "data.json",
        parse: function(data) {
            return data;
        }
  });

  return BranchCollection;
});
```

BranchView

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'collections/branch/BranchCollection', 'text!templates/locate-us/mapTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone, BranchCollection, mapTemplate) {
    var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#page"),
        initialize: function() {
            this.$el.off();
        },
        render: function(id) {
            var that = this;
            this.collection = new BranchCollection();
            var formValues = {
                id: id
            };
            this.collection.fetch({
                data: formValues,
                success: function(collection, response) {
                    that.$el.html(mapTemplate);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
        },
    });
    return MapView;
});
```

data.json

```
[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "KCP KEBAYORAN LAMA, FMT-JKT",
      "address":"Jl. Raya Kebayoran Lama No. 22 (PAL VII), Kel. Sukabumi Utara - Kec. Kebon Jeruk, Jakarta Barat 11540",
      "latitude":"-6.1773997",
      "longitude":"106.8409396"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "KK JL. PANJANG, PDI-JKT",
      "address":"Jl. Panjang No 37 D, RT 006, RW 011, Kecamatan Kebon Jeruk, Kelurahan Kebon Jeruk, Jakarta Barat",
      "latitude":"-6.1632894",
      "longitude":"106.7633571"
    }
]
```

Let say, i want to retrieve record id no 1, so I will get this values.

```
              "id": "1",
          "name": "KCP KEBAYORAN LAMA, FMT-JKT",
          "address":"Jl. Raya Kebayoran Lama No. 22 (PAL VII), Kel. Sukabumi Utara - Kec. Kebon Jeruk, Jakarta Barat 11540",
          "latitude":"-6.1773997",
          "longitude":"106.8409396"
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: what value  is contain in model ..?

Comment: i left it none, no default values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to fetch models by `id`, for this you need to provide a `urlRoot` in your `model`. For example :

```
var BranchModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
 urlRoot : '/branch'
});
```

This means that you have to have a urls for branch resource in your `Rest API`

```
/branch        // returns all branches
/branch/:id    // returns a single branch that has this id
```

And now you can start fetching the model by `id` as following

```
var model = new BranchModel({id:someId});
model.fetch();
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `this.collection.get("1")` ?

If your collection get the values from server properly, you can get the right thing you want with this code above.